# Centos проверить работу сервиса, если недоступен, перезапустить

Tags: centos, virtualbox

Есть сервер под управлением CentOs на котором установлена виртуальная машина с приложением. Запуск виртуальной машины осуществляется командой:

```
vboxmanage startvm "Application" --type headless
```

Как настроить, автоматическую проверку работоспособности этой виртуальной машины, и в случае "отказа", ее повторного перезапуска? Спасибо!

Comment: 1. `$ while:; do ... sleep ...; done` 2. https://superuser.com/q/622024/454489 3. как запустить — вы сами написали.

Comment: Вас не затруднит пояснить, как это будет выглядеть в одну строку?

Comment: `$ while :; do if не работает; then запстить; fi; sleep ...; done`